# Why do faces appear transparent when exported to a game engine?

Tags: faces

I created a low poly tree, and it's what I see in the editor:

[image: View within Blender]

But, in my 3D game engine (Godot Engine), this is how the tree looks:

[image]

(On the left, this is an icosphere created with Blender).

I don't know what part I missed, or what I done wrong for having this result with the 3D engine.

I started with a simple cube, cutting it and extruded it for this result, and I created manually near all the faces (except for the trunk). Then I exported the object in the Wavefront format (.obj).

Is my method wrong? Need I to recreate the whole object? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Start from adjusting face's normal orientation in your Blender model. Currently the looks like they are pointing inside and not outside. Then, if there are still problems, update your question with further info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching the normals?
If not, select the entire object whilst in Edit Mode. And press Crtl + N